# Changing the text color for UIImage or UIGraphics

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am going to implement the module for adding the numbers in WHITE color onto the arrow heads of the `UIImage` being drawn onto the ios apps. When it comes to the execution, it shows that only black color is set on the the numbers.  I have added

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
```

but to no avail. Would you please tell which is the better way to do so ?

The below is my  working

```
-(UIImage*) drawText:(NSString*) text
             inImage:(UIImage*)  image
             atPoint:(CGPoint)   point
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];

    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24];

    if([text respondsToSelector:@selector(drawInRect:withAttributes:)])
    {
        //IOS 7
        NSDictionary *att = @{NSFontAttributeName:font};
        [text drawInRect:rect withAttributes:att];
    }
    else
    {
        [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font];

    }
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how far back in time you want to go, pick any of these 3 solutions.
The 6+ and 7+ versions make use of `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` to select the color. These are the preferred methods.

**iOS 7+**

```
// (add the color to the attribute)
NSDictionary *att = @{NSFontAttributeName           :font,
                      NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]};
[@"test" drawInRect:rect withAttributes:att];
```

**iOS 6+** (works in iOS 7 too)

```
// (add the color to the attribute, using NSAttributedString)
NSDictionary *att = @{NSFontAttributeName           :font,
                      NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]};
NSAttributedString * text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"test"
                                                            attributes:att];
[text drawInRect:rect];
```

**iOS 5** (does not work on iOS 7)

```
// No attributes involved
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
[@"test" drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font];
```

Comment: Did. Could you rename post to something like "Changing the text color for UIImage or UIGraphics"?